# Is that possible to have embedded type parameters in Haxe, e.g. class Foo<Bar<T>>

Tags: haxe

Just a quick question.
Is it not possible to have embedded type parameters in Haxe?

```
class Foo<Bar<T>> {
}
```

The compiler (Haxe 2.10) complains with an "Unexpected <" error here…

**Edit: More details**

Say we have 3 classes/typedefs:

```
/** 
   this is a 2d grid storing a certain type
   Instead of a 2-dimensional array _a[x][y],
   it has a 1-dimensional internal array _a[directIndex]
 */
class Grid<T> {
    var _a:Array<T>;   // a single dimension Array for the grid
    public function new(width:Int, height:Int);
    public function iterator():Iterator<T> { return _a.iterator(); }
    public function iterator_coord():GridCoordIter<T> { return new GridCoordIter<T>(this); }
}

typedef GridCoord<T> = {
    var x: Int;
    var y: Int;
    var i: Int;        // direct index
    var v: T;
}

class GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>> {
    // .. some vars
    public function new(grid:Grid<T>);
    public function iterator():GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>> { return this; }
    // next(), hasNext()
}
```

The line `class GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>> {` refuses to compile.

I guess the class is type parametered to T, so just type `class GridCoordIter<T> {}`, right?
But since I want this iterator to be iterable, a line like `public function iterator():GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>> { return this; }` is needed.
And since we `return this`, the type of the class really seems to have to be `class GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>>`.

I can't see a way to get away with this contradiction right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out GridCoordIter is type parametered by T only.
So `class GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>>` should be written `class GridCoordIter<T>`.

As for the `public function iterator():GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>> { return this; }`, we can simply `return cast this;`.

So change:

```
class GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>> {
    // .. some vars
    public function new(grid:Grid<T>);
    public function iterator():GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>> { return this; }
    // next(), hasNext()
}
```

To:

```
class GridCoordIter<T> {
    // .. some vars
    public function new(grid:Grid<T>);
    public function iterator():GridCoordIter<GridCoord<T>> { return cast this; }
    // next(), hasNext()
}
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

i have 2 questions:
- why haxe 2.10? it's really ancient. the current version is 3.1.3
- what `Foo<Bar<T>>` is supposed to mean? if you need constraints, the syntax is `Foo<T:Bar<T2>,T2>` or something

Comment: Your comment is certainly helpful, but it doesn't answer the question. Please update your reply with an actual solution to the problem, or remove it.

Comment: I am sorry, but I would really like to know what OP wanted to achieve with the syntax he mentioned and then I can answer the question.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately fresh users can't comment on questions.

Comment: This answer is on the right track, at least until we have more information about what you're expecting @avtw

Comment: I tried to reduce the problem to the maximum to make it more understandable, but seems like I reduced it too much. I'll complete the question some more.

Comment: As for Haxe 2.10 it's just I like the number, feels like the language of the 2010s. Just kidding, I don't see much reasons to change for now, but probably going to use it for the next projects.